# Photoshop Script to Replace Text, and save as PNG

Tags: scripting, save, spreadsheet, photoshop

So I have a photoshop template I've created. It's a phone number that needs to be replaced, and exported as a transparent PNG. I've already formatted it's position, font, color, etc, all of which will not change. (only the number will change). I'm trying to find, or create, a script which will automate most of this for me as I have over 200 documents that I need to create.

I'd like to either have a dialog box pop up to ask the phone number, as well as what to save the finished document as(with transparency), OR run a batch process which will create all the files based on a spreadsheet I've created
something like:

```
1-888-888-8888    |    "Michigan_101648356.png"
1-999-999-9999    |    "Colorado_498443562.png"
```

etc.

Is there either a script already created I can use/modify, or is there a way to do this at all?

Comment: What Operating System do you use?

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476728/find-and-replace-text-in-multiple-photoshop-files) for the fine/replace part of the script and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205168/java-script-for-save-for-web-in-photoshop-not-producing-good-quality-image/26258817#26258817) for the save to png part.